# Access image files on Android device using phonegap framework

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap 5.3.1 and Android 22. I am trying to use the Filetransfer api of phonegap to transfer the images to the remote server.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();          
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert("The filename here is : " + imageData);
```

so here the imageData prints

```
content //com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image/image%3A53
```

and the further the below code

```
imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

does assign options.fileName =  "image%3A53"

This is not the image name that I have on device. In my opinion this is causing an issue.

The javascript used to run the FileTransfer plugin says that the file is transferred successfully but I cannot find the file on the server(runing PHP).

The server response is as follows:

got response from server

```
  Array
  (
      [file] => Array
          (
              [name] => image%3A53
              [type] => image/jpeg
              [tmp_name] => /tmp/php8qjZXN
              [error] => 0
              [size] => 137490
          )
  )
```

Also few posts say:
[Phonegap android unable to upload image using fileTransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754299/phonegap-android-unable-to-upload-image-using-filetransfer)

You can not use imageUri that you get from camera success callback in FileTransfer upload method, you have to first resolve uri as a filename like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){

      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {

                var fileName = fileObj.fullPath;

                //now use the fileName in your method
                //ft.upload(fileName ,serverURL + '/ajax.php?fname=appuploadspotimage'...);

            });
        });
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is 137490 bytes the correct file size? If so, I'd say your server is getting the file. What do you find at `/tmp/php8qjZXN`?

Comment: The size of the file seems correct. Also I get the following                       -bash: cd: /tmp/php8qjZXN: No such file or directory

Comment: Could we see the PHP that processes the request and stores the file?

Comment: <?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/myUser/public_html/app/public/".$new_image_name);
?>

Comment: Does it look like an error with the PHP script?

Comment: The PHP looks fine. What if you set `options.fileName = 'test-filename.jpg'`? If that works, it'd point the way to a solution.

Comment: some issue with the resolution of the file. Working om the below post                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638932/unable-to-load-image-when-selected-from-the-gallery-on-android-4-4-kitkat-usin

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. The issue was not on the client side but was on the server side.
I referred the below post:
[fileupload success, but no photos in the server (phonegap android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755626/fileupload-success-but-no-photos-in-the-server-phonegap-android)

The crux is "Have you checked your folder and script permissions? They both should have the same user/group. If you're running Apache,it would be something like apache:apache. From the cmd line you can run chown apache:apache upload.php then chown -R apache:apache php/"

The function move_upload_file([source],[destination]). The path to your images folder should be somewhere under your web site root directory. The uploaded files are moved from /tmp to your upload folder. That folder(and script doing the work) needs to be owned by apache.

I made the permissions as mentioned above and it worked. Thanks all for all your timely responses.